# Used explode to convert php string to array, need help manipulating this in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, arrays

I am sending an array in php (converted from a string using explode), to a seperate javascript page. I was wondering how do I get into the javascript array and actually retrieve data values.

array in javascript (from php file)-

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "30"
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "30"
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Here is the ajax call on the javascript page -

```
$.ajax({
    url: "GetTest.php",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data){
     alert("success");
     console.log(data);  
    },
    error: function(data){
     alert('failure'); 
    }
});
```

on the php page -

```
var_dump((explode(',', $something));
```

How do I get in here and pull out the "30" value. I am using an ajax call to get this data, and then putting placing this array in a variable called "data", but if I do something like data[0], I get the letter "a" as a response.
Any help towards this will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Please add the PHP code, that provides the AJAX response.

Comment: also add the php code which generates the array above. You'll generally want to use json_encode($array) in php and then JSON.parse() when the data gets to the client side.

Comment: What does the console.log(data) report?

Comment: it reports whats in the first grey box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JavaScript array should look like this...

```
var myArray = ["30", "0"];
```

You probably have a string instead of an array if you get an 'a' at index 0.

```
"array"[0] === "a"
```

So you need to fix your client side array first.

Answer (score 3):

If you are returning the array itself, it will not be converted to a JavaScript object. I believe you will just get the string "Array". What you need to do is call `json_encode($your_array)` to convert the array to a JavaScript object. Then, PHP will return a JavaScript object that looks like this:

```
{
  "0": "30",
  "1": ""
}
```

You can then call JSON.parse on the response and access the data in that object as you would any other JavaScript object.

**Note:** If you are using PHP < 5.2 and do not have the JSON PECL extension installed, the `json_encode()` function will not be available, and you will need to either write a function to convert an array to JSON or find one that someone else has written.

Answer (score 0):

In pure javascript:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()//where xhr is your request object
{
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)
    {
        var yourArray = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(yourArray);//logs the array above, normally
    }
};
```

Be aware that IE, prior to 9 at least, does not come with JSON support as standard, in which case, just google JSON.js and include it in the header.
 Also make sure that the array you send is `json_encode`'ed before you echo it.

Looking at the code you added, I'd say: replace the var_dump by `echo json_encode(explode(',',$someString));` and you're all set